# Can you subscribe to a YouTube channel as a podcast?

Tags: youtube, rss, video, podcasts

Videos are available in several different formats on YouTube, and RSS feeds are provided for channels. Is there a feed that will allow me to subscribe in iTunes?

Answer (score 7):

[Listenbox](https://listenbox.app/) does this. It supports videos, playlists, channels, plus you can queue items to listen later

Answer (score 6):

This question haunted me as well, and all the available options either didn't work or didn't fit... So I made my own: [YouCast](http://youcast.i3arnon.com/)

- It's free and open sourced.
- It works for both channels and playlists.
- Supports both audio and video podcasts.
- Sorts by popularity.

Comment: Not for mac I guess.

Comment: @DantheMan No. It's in .Net Framework. I have started working on a hosted version in the cloud but it doesn't have a UI yet.

Answer (score 6):

The web app [Podsync.net](http://podsync.net/) converts a YouTube channel URL into a podcast-compatible feed URL.

[image]

**Figure 1: Podsync.net web interface**

Comment: doesn't work anymore, you need to host it yourself

Answer (score 3):

I am using [www.podtube.me](https://www.podtube.me) to make a RSS feed to subscribe a youtube channel as a podcast in my podcast app.

Answer (score 2):

I am suprised Podsync has not been mentioned as an answer here! Podsync can turn any Youtube or Vimeo video, Ccannel or playlist in to a subscribable playlist that you can directly sync with your podcast app! I use it and just copy the link to Player FM, which I use on Android. In Player FM the playlists supposedly become public, so beware if making podcasts out of private videos!

[Podsync](http://podsync.net/)

Comment: doesn't work anymore, you need to host it yourself

Answer (score -1):

[Tubelivery](http://tubelivery.com/en/) works great! Load the app and use it to sign up for YouTube Channels. The Channels "automagically" show up in your iPhone podcasts! When I first did it nothing seemed to happen (a blank podcast page was created), but after a short while the content showed up. You need to use Tubelivery to add channels, but channel content (selecting episodes) is all done within Podcasts. Very nice solution.

http://tubelivery.com/en/

Comment: I get a "Out of service" message. I guess it doesn't work anymore

Comment: Hi, I'm the creator of Tubelivery and I had to turn it of. You can download the source code from here: https://bitbucket.org/tubelivery

Answer (score -2):

looks like http://www.ytpodcaster.com/ can convert a youtube rss-feed into something itunes likes.

Comment: Have you tested it? It doesn't work for me.

Comment: seems like this solution is out of business, their server return nothing valid. so, yes .. i tested it but it does not work. maybe if they get their servers working correct again.

Answer (score -2):

http://www.rsshandler.com/converter .. these generated podcasts at least appear in itunes, though i can't download any video so far. the converter creates the right feed, but the data returned by youtube is not in .mp4.

Answer (score -2):

[Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com) can do this, here's one that should be a good starting point: [youtube Channel to RSS](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=fa7cd649be5345f886b49e52ec9c51b8).

Comment: it relies on youtubemp4.com, and doesn't work anymore :(

Comment: Yahoo Pipes was retired.